# How to take a 2d list of strings and return a dict? first elements of each row are keys

Tags: python-3.x

Take a 2D list (i.e., list of lists) of strings. It returns a dictionary whose keys are the first elements of each row, and where each such key is mapped to the list consisting of the remaining elements of that row.

Been on geeks for geeks trying to figure this out. I get how to get to the first list I want to pull from, but I don't know how to go to each list after and then put it as a value in a new dictionary with the remaining strings as values in the dictionary.

```
def list2dict(list2d):
    new_dict = {}
    for i in range(list2d[0]):
        for j in range(2):
            new_dict.append[j] + ':' + list2d[j]
        return new_dict


list2d is a 2d list of strings

Input:

1. Let x1 be the following list of lists:
[ [ 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd' ],
  [ 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'jj' ],
  [ 'kk', 'll', 'mm', 'nn' ] ]

Output:
Then list2dict(x1) returns the dictionary
{ 'aa' : [ 'bb', 'cc', 'dd' ],
  'ee' : [ 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'jj' ],
  'kk' : [ 'll', 'mm', 'nn' ]
}

Input
2. Let x2 be the following list of lists:
[ [ 'aa', 'bb' ],
  [ 'cc', 'dd' ],
  [ 'ee', 'ff' ],
  [ 'gg', 'hh' ],
  [ 'kk', 'll' ] ]

Output
Then list2dict(x2) returns the dictionary
{ 'aa' : [ 'bb' ],
  'cc' : [ 'dd' ],
  'ee' : [ 'ff' ],
  'gg' : [ 'hh' ],
  'kk' : [ 'll' ]
}
```

Comment: did u forget to provide the rest of your code?

Comment: yeah, sorry I was working on it as I was posting.

Comment: def list2dict(list2d):
    new_dict = {}
    for i in range(list2d[0]):
        for j in range(2):
            new_dict.append[j] + ':' + list2d[j]
        return new_dict

Comment: in the question please, also what is `list2d`, please provide an example for hthe same and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this...
[Online Version](https://onlinegdb.com/r1e8pUkJyB)

```
def list2dict(list2d):
    new_dict = {}
    for i in list2d:
        key = i[0]
        list = i[1:len(i)]
        new_dict[key] = list
    print(new_dict)
    return new_dict
```